# Docker proxy config not working for ADD in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, proxy, dockerfile

I try to write a Dockerfile that adds a file to the image like this:

```
ADD https://repository.internal/file.zip /tmp/
```

The `repository.internal` host is only reachable through a proxy. I provide the proxy configuraton with the `--config` option but the `ADD` command seems not to use the proxy and fails.

I know the proxy configuration is correct because I added the line

```
RUN curl https://repository.internal/file.zip
```

which is working fine.

Is there any possibility to run the `ADD` command also with the proxy config?

Comment: I would imagine that this is something to do with the build layering that Docker performs to build your images, and that the ADD is using a slightly different method than the RUN ones... I cant find any documentation to back this up, however makes sense in my head as the RUN performs something ON the image being build, where as the ADD performs something then puts the RESULT of that into the image - Maybe Docker is using a build context outside of the network you need to perform that ADD command.

Could you use 'RUN curl xxxx > /tmp/file.zip && unzip /tmp/file.zip?

Comment: Thanks, yes that would make sense. I'm using the `curl` method you proposed as a workaround right now and it's working fine. But it's not ideal since curl may not be available on any image and therefore must be installed first just for this workaround. Anyway it is something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments above, I *believe* this to be something to do with the internal way the Docker build process handles the `ADD` and `RUN` commands... I cant find documentation to back this up - so someone with greater internal knowledge may confirm or deny, but makes sense as a `RUN` command is done in a layer TO the image being built, where as the `ADD` command is performed and the *results* of it are baked into the image.

Whichever way this is being handled, you can achieve what you need by moving to the `RUN` method as follows:

```
FROM <your base image>

RUN curl https://repository.internal/file.zip >> /tmp/file.zip \
    && cd /tmp \ 
    && unzip file.zip \
    && rm file.zip
```

And you will have the files unzipped.

*You may need to check if the `rm` at the end is required - cant remember off the top of my head if the unzip command removes the original zip file.*

As you mentioned, this would rely on the `curl` and `unzip` packages being available on the image... however you could potentially avoid having these within your final application image by using [Docker Multi Stage Builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Your Dockerfile would then look something like:

```
FROM <some useful base image> as collector

RUN apt-get install -y curl unzip
RUN mkdir /tmp/files && \
    && curl https://repository.internal/file.zip >> /tmp/files/file.zip \
    && cd /tmp/files \ 
    && unzip file.zip \
    && rm file.zip

FROM <your final desired base image>

COPY --from=collector /tmp/files /tmp
```

This would then utilise an image to have `curl` and `unzip` in to collect and deal with the extraction of your files without having to install them on your final application image.

Comment: Just for completeness. `unzip` does not remove the zip thus `rm` is needed.